# Lightsail load balancer support WebSocket Secure (WSS)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, websocket, actioncable, amazon-lightsail

I am currently creating a monolithic application on Rail (7.0.3), have created a chat application using Action Cable and WebSocket communication.
I am using LightSail, which is easy to build, but does the Lightsail load balancer support WebSocket communication? or Do I need to make changes to the ALB on LightSail?